# MQTT js library, Can't connect to broker over websocket in Google Chrome , but it works well in FireFox

Tags: javascript, reactjs, websocket, mqtt

I'm facing a problem and I've tried to find the solution, but nothing has worked for me. I'm using the MQTT.js library to connect with the broker server. My code is below.
( video : https://youtu.be/5e9lRZM4o8I )

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script
      src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mqtt/4.3.7/mqtt.min.js"
      integrity="sha512-tc5xpAPaQDl/Uxd7ZVbV66v94Lys0IefMJSdlABPuzyCv0IXmr9TkqEQvZiWKRoXMSlP5YPRwpq2a+v5q2uzMg=="
      crossorigin="anonymous"
      referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

    <script>
      try {
        const client = mqtt.connect('ws://test.mosquitto.org:8080/mqtt');

        client.on('connect', () => {
          console.log('Connected');
        });
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

everything is very simple. But when i try to access my site using google chrome i got the error.

[image]
[image]
[image]
When i use FireFox or chrome in incognito mode, everything works well

[image]

Everyone who has worked with this library or knows some solutions, can you help me with that? Thank you so much.

Comment: what is `chrome in ignition mode`?

Comment: By the way, ran your code and it works fine in Chrome, since I don't know what "ignition mode" is, I doubt I'm using it

Comment: You have blocked out the broker address, but the code points at test.mosquitto.org, if you are not actually using that broker then you must supply the configuration details if the broker you are using

Comment: sorry guy  i mean "ctrl shift n" mode in chrome.

Comment: I don't block anything as you can see in the video I included with my question. I am using the same code across multiple browsers, and everything works well except for Google Chrome. I believe the issue is with Google Chrome not the broker server.

Comment: Watch the video; it will give you a better understanding.

Comment: All relevant information should be in the question not a video

Comment: Take the `.min` out of the cnd link to the MQTT.js code so you get a useful stack trace

Comment: i did it but nothing more informations, same error, i also try with different version of this library. i tried in my PC and Laptop.

Comment: I can duplicate the issue and agree that the unminimised version does not provide much more info (fails at `new WebSocket(...`. Works fine with `wss` (port 8081) so looks like chrome security model (Firefox is fine).

Comment: Wireshark shows TCP sync/ack/fin from the default Chrome, closing the socket before trying to send any HTTP requests. I suggest your only option here is to raise a bug against Chrome. But when you do you MUST not blank out sections of the images and the port numbers must match.

Answer (score -1):

I woked with mqtt in a React project. Your code seems fine, however one difference is the url you use to connect, try this one :

mqtt://test.mosquitto.org:8081

Here is a working example in React :

```
const url = "mqtt://test.mosquitto.org:8081";
const [client, setClient] = useState(null);

const mqttConnect = () => {
    const client = mqtt.connect(url);
    setClient(client);
  };


useEffect(() => {
    mqttConnect();
}, []);


 useEffect(() => {
    if (client) {
      client.on("connect", () => {
        console.log("connected");

      client.on("error", (err) => {
        console.error("Connection error: ", err);
        client.end();
      });

      client.on("reconnect", () => {
        console.log("Reconnecting");
      });
    }
  }, [client]);
```

Comment: You can not connect to `mqtt://` from a browser, it must be a `ws://` or `wss://`. The MQTT.js client will change it for you on the fly

Comment: you're right, can't use mqtt:// in browser, in my case i use ws:// . but something wrong with google chrome ???. Everyone who can give me some advice. I try on both my PC and latop, but i got same error.